# Lighting planes (openGL)

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I'd like to enable lighting in my openGL program, i already works for objects drawn with GLUT.
but when i draw my cuuboid

```
glBegin(5);
glVertex3f((x_+(b/2)),y_,(z_-(l/2)));
glVertex3f((x_+(b/2)),y_,(z_+(l/2)));
glVertex3f((x_-(b/2)),y_,(z_-(l/2)));
glVertex3f((x_-(b/2)),y_,(z_+(l/2)));
glVertex3f((x_+(b/2)),y_t,(z_-(l/2)));
glVertex3f((x_+(b/2)),y_t,(z_+(l/2)));
glVertex3f((x_-(b/2)),y_t,(z_-(l/2)));
glVertex3f((x_-(b/2)),y_t,(z_+(l/2)));
glVertex3f((x_+(b/2)),y_,(z_-(l/2)));
glVertex3f((x_+(b/2)),y_t,(z_-(l/2)));
glVertex3f((x_+(b/2)),y_,(z_+(l/2)));
glVertex3f((x_+(b/2)),y_t,(z_+(l/2)));
glVertex3f((x_-(b/2)),y_,(z_-(l/2)));
glVertex3f((x_-(b/2)),y_t,(z_-(l/2)));
glVertex3f((x_-(b/2)),y_,(z_+(l/2)));
glVertex3f((x_-(b/2)),y_t,(z_+(l/2)));
glVertex3f((x_-(b/2)),y_,(z_-(l/2)));
glVertex3f((x_-(b/2)),y_t,(z_-(l/2)));
glVertex3f((x_+(b/2)),y_,(z_-(l/2)));
glVertex3f((x_+(b/2)),y_t,(z_-(l/2)));
glVertex3f((x_-(b/2)),y_,(z_+(l/2)));
glVertex3f((x_-(b/2)),y_t,(z_+(l/2)));
glVertex3f((x_+(b/2)),y_,(z_+(l/2)));
glVertex3f((x_+(b/2)),y_t,(z_+(l/2)));
glEnd();
```

with

```
glColor3f(6,0,0);
```

lightning isn't applied on its surfaces. (the cuboid is drawn correct)

my lighning is set up like this:

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

const GLfloat light_ambient[]  = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat light_diffuse[]  = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat light_specular[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat light_position[] = { 2.0f, 5.0f, 1.0, 1.0f };

const GLfloat mat_ambient[]    = { 0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat mat_diffuse[]    = { 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat mat_specular[]   = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat high_shininess[] = { 100.0f };

glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT,  light_ambient);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE,  light_diffuse);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, light_specular);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);

glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT,   mat_ambient);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE,   mat_diffuse);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR,  mat_specular);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, high_shininess);
```

does anyone know the flaw i make?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give it any normals.  You need to use glNormal3f to specify the normals.

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
glNormal3f(0,1,0);
glVertex3f((x_+(b/2)),y_,(z_-(l/2)));
glVertex3f((x_+(b/2)),y_,(z_+(l/2)));
glVertex3f((x_-(b/2)),y_,(z_-(l/2)));
glVertex3f((x_-(b/2)),y_,(z_+(l/2)));
glNormal3f(-1,0,0);
// etc.
```

Comment: so i used glNormal3f in front of every plane i draw, like this:
`glNormal3f(0,1,0);
    glVertex3f((x_+(b/2)),y_,(z_-(l/2)));
    glVertex3f((x_+(b/2)),y_,(z_+(l/2)));
    glVertex3f((x_-(b/2)),y_,(z_-(l/2)));
    glVertex3f((x_-(b/2)),y_,(z_+(l/2)));`

Comment: but it did'nt changed anything

Comment: @AndiFaust: Different sides have different normals.

Comment: i know. i did apply different normals to different planes - in the consens of your code example.

Comment: but itdidn't change anything

Comment: @AndiFaust: What is y_t?  The top y coordinate?

Comment: yes. but i solved my problem. the color was too high. thanks!